# Python tensorflow keras error when load a json model: Could not locate class 'Sequential'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I've built and trained my model weeks ago and saved it on model.json dan model.h5

Today, when I tried to load it using model_from_json, it gives me an error

```py
TypeError: Could not locate class 'Sequential'. Make sure custom classes are decorated with `@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()`. Full object config: {'class_name': 'Sequential', 'config': {'name': 'sequential_7', 'layers': [{'module': 'keras.layers', 'class_name': 'InputLayer', 'config': {'batch_input_shape': [None, 244, 244, 3], 'dtype': 'float32', 'sparse': False, 'ragged': False, 'name': 'conv2d_15_input'}, 'registered_name': None}, {'module': 'keras.layers', 'class_name': 'Conv2D', 'config': {'name': 'conv2d_15', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'batch_input_shape': [None, 244, 244, 3], 'filters': 32, 'kernel_size': [3, 3], 'strides': [1, 1], 'padding': 'valid', 'data_format': 'channels_last', 'dilation_rate': [1, 1], 'groups': 1, 'activation': 'relu', 'use_bias': True, 'kernel_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'GlorotUniform', 'config': {'seed': None}, 'registered_name': None}, 'bias_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}, 'registered_name': None}, 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_constraint': None}, 'registered_name': None, 'build_config': {'input_shape': [None, 244, 244, 3]}}, {'module': 'keras.layers', 'class_name': 'MaxPooling2D', 'config': {'name': 'max_pooling2d_14', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'pool_size': [2, 2], 'padding': 'valid', 'strides': [2, 2], 'data_format': 'channels_last'}, 'registered_name': None, 'build_config': {'input_shape': [None, 242, 242, 32]}}, {'module': 'keras.layers', 'class_name': 'Conv2D', 'config': {'name': 'conv2d_16', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'filters': 64, 'kernel_size': [3, 3], 'strides': [1, 1], 'padding': 'valid', 'data_format': 'channels_last', 'dilation_rate': [1, 1], 'groups': 1, 'activation': 'relu', 'use_bias': True, 'kernel_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'GlorotUniform', 'config': {'seed': None}, 'registered_name': None}, 'bias_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}, 'registered_name': None}, 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_constraint': None}, 'registered_name': None, 'build_config': {'input_shape': [None, 121, 121, 32]}}, {'module': 'keras.layers', 'class_name': 'MaxPooling2D', 'config': {'name': 'max_pooling2d_15', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'pool_size': [2, 2], 'padding': 'valid', 'strides': [2, 2], 'data_format': 'channels_last'}, 'registered_name': None, 'build_config': {'input_shape': [None, 119, 119, 64]}}, {'module': 'keras.layers', 'class_name': 'Flatten', 'config': {'name': 'flatten_7', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'data_format': 'channels_last'}, 'registered_name': None, 'build_config': {'input_shape': [None, 59, 59, 64]}}, {'module': 'keras.layers', 'class_name': 'Dense', 'config': {'name': 'dense_14', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'units': 64, 'activation': 'relu', 'use_bias': True, 'kernel_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'GlorotUniform', 'config': {'seed': None}, 'registered_name': None}, 'bias_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}, 'registered_name': None}, 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_constraint': None}, 'registered_name': None, 'build_config': {'input_shape': [None, 222784]}}, {'module': 'keras.layers', 'class_name': 'Dense', 'config': {'name': 'dense_15', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'units': 2, 'activation': 'softmax', 'use_bias': True, 'kernel_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'GlorotUniform', 'config': {'seed': None}, 'registered_name': None}, 'bias_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}, 'registered_name': None}, 'kernel_regularizer': None, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_constraint': None}, 'registered_name': None, 'build_config': {'input_shape': [None, 64]}}]}, 'keras_version': '2.13.1', 'backend': 'tensorflow'}
```

I've imports all the requirements:

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import model_from_json

from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img, img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
```

And this is my code used to load the saves json model:

```py
json_file = open('./model/model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe Keras has some breaking change, do you have the same version of Keras as when you serialized to json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the version because of @kartoos comments. Yes, my kaggle's notebook use tensorflow version 2.13.1 meanwhile I'm trying to load the model to 2.16.1 Tensorflow version.

I tried to install 2.13.1 but i can't find a way, so I'm build and re-train my model using 2.16.1 version tensorflow, and it works, no more error and the model can works fine when get saved and loaded again.

Saved the model as keras instead of json

```py
model.save('model.keras')
```

and load the model again

```py
loaded_model = keras.models.load_model("./model/model.keras")
```

Thanks !